# ASP.NET Notifications for changes in database

Tags: asp.net

We have a window application and a web application, and both connect to a same database to handle data. User on web application will do some changes and wait for the approve from users on window application. Is there any way to show a live update or notification on web application whenever an approve is made at window application which is lead to change in database? 
Note: we use ASP.NET for web application and .NET for windows application

Comment: What is your database technology?

Comment: Have you tried using AJAX? That could help.

Comment: To ck: We use MS SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: To JMichelIB: I have never used AJAX before, but can you provide more detail about what I can use with AJAX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refresh a portion of the page periodically using AJAX.  I would use jquery for the ajax stuff: [jquery.com](http://www.jquery.com)

Not sure how long the approval process is expected to take, but you could set the page to poll the server every 5 seconds, 15 seconds, whatever makes sense.  If it's just refreshing a small portion of the page, it shouldn't be too much of a burden on the server relative to reloading the entire page at every interval.

Answer (score 3):

This link which talks about [SQLDependency and Query Notification](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/156991-using-sqldependency-to-monitor-sql-database-changes/) seems to be what you are looking for.

You could setup a "notification" area within an updatepanel, or just use straight up ajax to make queries to the database on a specified interval as well.

There are several options.

Answer (score 2):

you can refresh your ASP.NET page by regular interval. http://www.devcurry.com/2009/03/how-to-refresh-aspnet-gridview.html

Comment: I'd suggest doing the refresh with ajax calls, but yeah, good idea.